# Convert 300 CSV files to one 2D Array in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have about 300 data in CSV format. I want to convert them into a 2D array with Python. Each CSV file has one column with about 150,000 entries. The head of the CSV is the label.
After conversion into the array, the first row of the array should be the first CSV file, the second row of the array should be the second CSV file, and so on.
At the end I want to have an array with 300 rows and 150,000 columns. The first column should contain the label.
I hope you can help me with this problem.

Thank you very much.

So far i have written the code to loop through the folder with the csv files

```
def CSV_File_Loop(Path_Fil):
    files = [join(Path_File,f) for f in listdir(Path_file) if isfile(join  (Path_File,f) and ".csv" in f]
    for file in files:
        d=pandas.read_csv(file, header = None)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header = None) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1).T
```

Test

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(150000)) for i in range(300)]
df = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1).T
print (df.shape)
```

Output

```
(300, 150000)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.
I still have a small question, how do I convert df into a new CSV?

Comment: df.to_csv("thefilename.csv")